# Score base on 2 variable algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, math, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game, I want to check if the user received a higher score than his previous score. The score will be based on time taken and number of attempts. The shorter the time and the lesser the attempts, the higher the score will be.

What should be the algorithm to calculate the score?

Comment: arithmetic comparison

Comment: @JaromandaX I know how to compare but what to compare?

Comment: it's unclear from your question

Comment: You have to show us some code

Answer (score 0):

```
Total Score = Base Score - (Time Penalty + Attempts Penalty)

Time Penalty = Seconds * (Base Score * Time Penalty Const)
```

Where Time penalty const its a % of the base score that you want to subtract for each second for example ...
Time Penalty Const = 0.01 
1% from the base score each second
Same goes for Attempts Penalty.

If Total Score reach a value less than 0 game over

Comment: there's no base score here.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go with Score = Constant / (NumberOfAttempts * Time)

This way, score decreases with longer time and higher attempts, then you can scale it however you please with said constant.

However, a better algorithm is difficult to find given so little context.

Comment: That can be your choice. Say for example, you wanted your score to be 100 if the user made 1 attempt and it took 1 second, then that constant would be 100. If you wanted the score to be 100 when the user made 1 attempt in 1 minute, then that constant would be 6000, since 6000/(1*60) = 100.

You can choose this constant to be anything to help you to scale the score for display, operate on, etc.